# How to match a class with annotation inside?

Tags: byte-buddy

I have an annotation named `Metric`

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Metric {
    String name() default "";
}
```

I want to weave some logic when some methods with the `@Metric` annotation, like:

```
public class MethodWithMetricDemo{

    @Metric
    public void targetMethod(){
        // do some thing
    }
}
```

But how to match the class `MethodWithMetricDemo` in `new AgentBuilder.Default().type(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to match your type based on the method annotatation. As methods are inherited virtually, you would however need to travers the entire class hierarchy by `hasSuperType(declaresMethod(isAnnotatedWith(...)))`. This is possible but rather expensive. If you choose to use such a matcher, you should probably restrict your matching to a given namespace.